# Why does this drop-shadow appear only if overflow-x is available?

Tags: safari, tailwind-css

This is only observed on **Safari** Version 15.6 (17613.3.9.1.5); Firefox seems to render as expected.

Observe the following via the Tailwind playground:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/CBCrf9Ujbt

The above has scrollable space on the x-axis. Now if we remove the long comment, observe the drop-shadow disappear:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/74dWNJOG0k

Why is this happening and how can we work around this such that the drop-shadow displays consistently?